# how to set Values in List of collection using SnakeYaml lib

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have following YAML

```
image:
  - repository: "test.com/test"
    pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    tag: "abctag"
route:
  hosts:
    - host: abc.bbc.com
    - host: bbc.abc.com
    - host: bbc1.abc.com
```

I want to add the new host entry in hosts section and save/rewrite the YANL file
Can it be possible using SnakeYAML file ? Please suggest

I have following code

```
public class Image {
    
    private String repository;
    private String pullPolicy;
    private String tag;
    
    public Image()
    {   
    }
    
    public Image (String repository, String pullPolicy, String tags)
    {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
        this.pullPolicy = pullPolicy;
        this.tag = tags;
        
    }
    
    public String getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
    public void setRepository(String repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public String getPullPolicy() {
        return pullPolicy;
    }
    public void setPullPolicy(String pullPolicy) {
        this.pullPolicy = pullPolicy;
    }
    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }
    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
    

}

public class Host {
    
      private String host;
        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }
        public void setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

}

public class Route {
    
       private List<Host> hosts = new ArrayList<Host>();
        public List<Host> getHosts() {
            return hosts;
        }
        public void setHosts(List<Host> hosts) {
            this.hosts = hosts;
        }

}

public class SnakeYaml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\yaml\\student.yaml"));
    
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Values.class));
    
        Values data = yaml.load(inputStream);
    
        data.getImage().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getTag()));
        data.getRoute().getHosts().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getHost()));

    }

}
```

Comment: please help / suggest